# SQL Server 2012 - Trying to Update value in table A if entry is not in table B using a JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, sql-update, execution-time

The following UPDATE statement does exactly what I want it to do:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Person]
SET [IsUpdated] = 0 
FROM [Person] p
WHERE p.IsUpdated = 1
  and p.PersonID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT q.PersonID FROM [DeletionQueue] d, [Queue] q
                         WHERE d.fkQueueID = q.QueueID)
```

However, when I run the Estimated execution plan for this statement, I see that 70% of my process time is consumed by the NOT IN SELECT statement. I would much rather achieve the same results using a JOIN statement of some sort.

I have tried to create the statement in a number of different ways, but the closest I have been able to come to replicating the above statement is one that gives me the exact opposite results of what I am looking for (i.e. If I have 2 persons in the Persons table with IsUpdated = 1, both persons have an entry in the Queue table (QueueID), but only person B is in the DeletionQueue table (fkQueueID), then only person A's record in the Person table should have IsUpdated changed to 0). Currently, when I try a JOIN statement, person B is updated and person A is not.

I can use the statement as is if necessary, but performance is pretty critical in this application.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have indexes on DeletionQueue.fkQueueID and Queue.QueueID columns?

Comment: I do have indexes on both DeletionQueue.fkQueueID and Queue.QueueID columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `NOT EXISTS` instead:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Person]
    SET [IsUpdated] = 0 
FROM [Person] p
WHERE
    p.IsUpdated = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM [DeletionQueue] d
        INNER JOIN [Queue] q
            ON q.fkQueueID = q.QueueID
        WHERE q.PersonId = p.PersonId
    )
```

According to this [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) by Aaron Bertrand:

> for the pattern of finding all rows in table A where some condition does not
>   exist in table B, `NOT EXISTS` is typically going to be your best
>   choice. But, as always, you need to test these patterns in your own
>   environment, using your schema, data and hardware, and mixed in with
>   your own workloads.

Comment: Thank you for the response Felix. If I am unable to find a way to do this without using a SELECT statement, I will definitely use the NOT EXISTS instead of the NOT IN as that will help with performance.  However, 70% of my time is still being spent on the SELECT query.

Comment: Do you mean the `SELECT` query inside the `NOT IN`? Try removing the `DISTINCT` clause.

Comment: Actually, I was meaning the 'SELECT' query within your snippet in the 'NOT EXISTS'. I still think this is going to be my best option though.  Thanks again.